# WAMP my own internal ip doesn't work on browser

Tags: php, apache

I have installed WAMP and my computer ip is `http://192.168.1.142/`
When I entered it in browser I got nothing, my WAMP server doesn't see this ip

I got error :

> **This 192.168.1.142 page can’t be found

No webpage was found for the web address:

> 192.168.1.142 HTTP ERROR 404**

http://prntscr.com/fx1mri

Tried configure `httpd.conf` Want add there row Listen 192.168.1.142:80 and when I run restart WAMP it's not green , means apache doesn't run ,

How correct this ? Why my local IP can't reach in my browser ?

Comment: Is there Linux or Windows OS?
What is in error.log file? What result of ipconfig or ifconfig command (depends on OS)?

Comment: Have you tried it with localhost in your browser?

Comment: "WAMP is not green" means that something in your stack is not running. Evidence indicates that it's the webserver. You should check the error logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there will be 2 approach to solve this-

1. You need to provide the ip-address instead of localhost in your code.
2. Try not to use Skype at the same time since it uses same port number.

Comment: yes, I off skype and got this http://prntscr.com/fx1t32 , this is what I must got  at first . And I want open access to my wamp over internet , how to do it ? I open port 3333 on my router forwarding port 3333

Answer (score 1):

If it's your local computer I'll recommend you to use "http://localhost" or "http://127.0.0.1". Prefer localhost.

If you want to use some other cool hostname you should add it to your (windows)hostfile %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Example of input:

```
127.0.0.1 localsecure
```

Answer (score 0):

Other programs like skype and torrent are usually using the same ports. Go to your httpd.conf and change `listen` to for example 82 and the servername to `localhost:82`(the port is always the same as the value of listen). And than you can use localhost everywhere for example your phpmyadmin would be:

```
localhost:82/phpmyadmin
```

And the directories:

```
localhost:82/..
```

*Credit: [ndsmyter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1264315/ndsmyter)*